# Simulating a synthetic mouse wheel event on input type number using Cypress

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, cypress

I am trying to simulate a mouse wheel event on an input type number on a react web application, using the Cypress Testing Framework. I am using `trigger` as per their docs (https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger.html) but it seems like there is very little information online as to how to actually create the synthetic event and what arguments it requires. This is what I have so far:

```
cy.get("#cost-amount-input")
        .click()
        .trigger("mouseover")
        //.trigger("mousewheel", {deltaY: 99})
        .trigger("wheel", { deltaY: -66.666666, wheelDelta: 120, wheelDeltaX: 0, wheelDeltaY: 120, bubbles: true})
        .blur()
        .then(() => {
          /* test if the mouse wheel event chagned the value as expected */
        });
```

Adding an event listener to the document for all wheel events shows that my event is firing, but it is not causing the value to change as happens when I do an actual mouse wheel event. Here are the two different events as captured by my event listener.
Cypress synthetic event (does not work)

[image: synthetic event which does not work]

Actual mouse wheel event (does work - changes the value):

[image: actual wheel event which does work]

Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Following the example here [MDN - Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events), I built a minimal example to reproduce the problem.

```html
<body>

  <input type="number" />

  <script>
    const event = new Event('wheel');
    const elem = document.querySelector('input');
    elem.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) { 
      elem.value = +elem.value + 1;  // treat input value as a number
    }, false);

    elem.dispatchEvent(event);  // dispatch an event to show it's working

  </script>
</body>
```

This is the test (passing).

```js
it('Cypress "trigger" fires synthetic event', () => {
  
  cy.visit('../app/synthetic-event.html');

  cy.get('input').invoke('val').should('eq', '1');  // input has '1' since event triggered on load

  cy.get('input').trigger("wheel");                 // trigger the synthetic event
  cy.get('input').invoke('val').should('eq', '2');  // confirm value has changed

})
```

---

The only practical difference I can see is your "Actual mouse wheel event" log shows negative `wheelDelta` and positive `deltaY`, whereas your test is showing the ***opposite*** polarity.

Perhaps the input does not allow change in the opposite direction (i.e negative input)?

Please share the code for event constructor and event listener.

Comment: Thanks for the minimal example. I think the difference is that I don't have any actual event listener on the number input, it seems like the default HTML behaviour is to allow a user to edit the value by scrolling, even without a custom event listener on it. In fact, the test I'm writing aims to assert that the value does not change, as I have added a custom listener to prevent the default behaviour. Here is that code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/ZdW1QOkY.

Comment: So, it's not a "synthetic event" as MDN defines it.

Comment: ***the test I'm writing aims to assert that the value does not change*** but in the test code `/* test if the mouse wheel event chagned the value as expected */`

Comment: Please explain why your test sends the opposite wheel direction to the actual event.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I think that's a red herring, I tried with both, as well as several other values with different magnitudes and polarities and it did not help. As far as the value goes I feel like I'm just guessing and nothing makes any difference. It's worth noting that for the default HTML behaviour of changing the value to trigger the input needs to be focused and the mouse needs to be hovering on the element. I tried adding .Focus().Trigger("mouseover") before firing the "wheel" event but nothing has helped so far.